# How to sum a variable and extract it related variable to appear in the answer

Tags: r, variables, sum, extract, r-factor

I am new to R and to Stackoverflow and I need an assistant in sorting and extracting information from a data frame I created. I need to extract which IATA and NAME has received the most commission. The result should print: 3301, you pay, 12. I can subset each and every IATA but it is a long process. What will be the best function in R to sort all this information and print out this information.

```
  IATA          NAME TICKET_NUM            PAX FARE TAX COMM NET
3300      pay more        700     john cohen   10 1.1    2   8
3300      pay more        701     james levy   11 1.2    2   9
3300      pay more        702 jonathan arbel   12 1.2    3   9
3300      pay more        703      gil matan    9 1.0    2   7
3301      you pay         704      ron natan   19 2.0    6   9
3301      you pay         705    don horvitz   18 2.0    6   9
3302 pay by ticket        706  lutter kaplan    9 1.2    0   9
3303         enjoy        707   lutter omega   12 1.2    0  12
3303         enjoy        708   graig daniel   14 1.3    1  13
3303         enjoy        730 orly rotenberg   15 1.0    1  14
3303         enjoy        731     yohan bach   12 1.0    1  11
```

Comment: Why did you remove the data set?  Answering the question without the data will be difficult.  If you want to identify the maximum commission by some group, try using `tapply` or `aggregate`.

Comment: it doesn't let me add an attachment since I am new. However when I tried to copy and paste the table it spread it all over the page

Comment: Why does `enjoy` have the most commission?  Is `COMM` the commission or is `NET` the commission?

Comment: if you indent the lines of the table by 4 spaces they get a code box which keeps spacing and makes it look nice.

Comment: The maximum COMM is 6 and that is for 3301 and NAME you pay.  I do not understand why you expect to obtain the number 12.  Do you want the line containing the maximum COMM for each IATA?  Sorry, but I am too confused to help.

Comment: I need to find the travel agent name and IATA number that received the most commission.'you pay' sold two ticket and they received a total commission of $12. The other travel agents received less

Comment: Maybe you want to sum COMM by IATA and identify which IATA / NAME has the maximum total COMM?  In that case 3301 and you pay still has the maximum value (of 12).  If so, why do you want the NAME enjoy?

Comment: you are right, I don't know why I mentioned enjoy. But what you described above is exactly what I need to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to return what you requested (using Jeremy's code for the second part):

```
comm <- read.table(text = '

IATA          NAME TICKET_NUM            PAX FARE TAX COMM NET
3300      pay.more        700     john.cohen   10 1.1    2   8
3300      pay.more        701     james.levy   11 1.2    2   9
3300      pay.more        702 jonathan.arbel   12 1.2    3   9
3300      pay.more        703      gil.matan    9 1.0    2   7
3301       you.pay        704      ron.natan   19 2.0    6   9
3301       you.pay        705    don.horvitz   18 2.0    6   9
3302 pay.by.ticket        706  lutter.kaplan    9 1.2    0   9
3303         enjoy        707   lutter.omega   12 1.2    0  12
3303         enjoy        708   graig.daniel   14 1.3    1  13
3303         enjoy        730 orly.rotenberg   15 1.0    1  14
3303         enjoy        731     yohan.bach   12 1.0    1  11

', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

comm2 <- with(comm, aggregate(COMM ~ IATA + NAME, FUN = function(x) sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)))
comm2

max_comm <- comm2[comm2$COMM == max(comm2$COMM),]
max_comm

  IATA    NAME COMM
4 3301 you.pay   12
```

Here is an explanation of the first statement:

The `with` function identifies the data set to use (here `comm`).  The function `aggregate` is a general function for performing operations on groups. You want to operate on `COMM` by `IATA` and `NAME`.  You write that: `COMM ~ IATA + NAME`.  Next you specify the desired function to perform on `COMM` (here `sum`).  You do that with `FUN = function(x) sum(x)`.  In case there are any missing observations in `COMM` I added `na.rm = TRUE` within the `sum(x)` function.

Comment: Thank you! Can you please explain the first command? the request to aggregate, the tilde and the function you created. What each function created in the data frame.

Comment: @EP_NYC I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Call that table `comm`

```
max_comm <- comm[comm$COMM == max(comm$COMM),]
```

or just sort it and look at the head

```
head(comm[order(-comm$COMM),])
```

Edit: If you want to sum by IATA first then use data.table

```
library(data.table)
comm2 <- data.table(comm)
sum_comm <- comm2[, list(COMM_SUM=sum(COMM)), by = c("IATA","NAME")]
```

`data.table` has an unusual syntax, you could also try `dplyr` which is supposed to be roughly as good as `data.table` now

Comment: He wants to sum COMM by IATA and identify the IATA with the maximum sum.

Comment: Thank you so much! Good night!